# Mahapps : ScrollViewer update list on event KeyDown in WPF ( C # )

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a problem I can not solve.

As you can see in the picture , there is a label , a textobx and a ScrollViewer .

Now , I have to update the ScrollViewer when the user searches through the textbox .
Part of an event every time you make a keydown .

So if I write Statut ... should put first in the file list with the names "statuto rai"

the list can have N elements

**Image list:**

[image]

**Xaml code:**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="GhostWhite"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Documenti allegati</TextBlock>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" BorderBrush="White" Height="22" Background="#fff">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="#465E76" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" Background="#fff" Foreground="#565656" controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Ricerca Locale" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Thin}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ></TextBox>
        </Border>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="Both" Name="scrollDocuments">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=attachmentsList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="450"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#fff"></Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="10,3,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding contList}"/>
                                            <Image Source="/Resources/Images/icon-document-browser.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,-12,0,0" Width="22"/>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="21,32,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding FileSizeConverted}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Margin="55,-10,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Margin="55,-10,10,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="{Binding ModifiedDate}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="55,25,10,0" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}" Text="Nessuna copia locale"/>
                                            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="#DDD" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"></Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="2" Name="testoNessunAllegato" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="20">
            <TextBlock Text="Nessun allegato disponibile."></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

**CodeBehind event code:**

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string find = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
            attachmentsList = attachmentsList.Where(x => x.Name == find).ToList();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

in practice I do the intelligiente research, so every time I insert a letter filtrale list , and print it again , of course real time .

I hope I explained myself .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see you use bindings, in this case there is a much better stuff to reach your goal. It's CollectionView.

Here is a simple app for you which more or less fullfill your requirements:

**View**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Search" />
    <TextBox MinWidth="30" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
```

*UpdateSorceTrigger=PropertyChanges* updates FilterText in ViewModel every time when you press any key.
*Data* is a ***ICollectionView***

**ViewModel**

```
public ICollectionView Data { get; private set; }

...
// Create default view for the list
Data = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list);
// Set filter delegate for CollectionView
Data.Filter = FilterData;

....
private bool FilterData(object obj)
{
        DataContainer cont = (DataContainer)obj;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterText) || cont.Name.StartsWith(FilterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

private string myfiltertext;
public string FilterText
{
    get { return myfiltertext; }
    set
    {
        myfiltertext = value;
        // Refresh collection view after Filter text modification
        Data.Refresh();
    }
}
```